# Finding the subset of a dictionary that has the minimum edit distance to a given string

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, strings, string-matching, edit-distance

I'm looking for the most efficient way of solving an [Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) problem.

We are given as input:

> 1. A set of strings `S` of size `n` <= 8, with average length `m` <= 50
> 2. A target string `t` of length `l` <= 50

Our task is to 'align' `t` with `S` i.e:

> Find the subset `s*` of `S`, where `concat(s*)` has the minimum Levenshtein edit distance (among all the subsets) with `t`

Some thoughts:

1. For 2 strings of length `l1` and `l2`, we could use the standard dynamic programming algorithm which has `O(l1*l2)` time complexity
2. Brute forcing this would require us to compute `editDistance(t, concat(s')) for each subset s'`. This would be approximately `O(l.m.n!)`
3. This could be optimized a bit by memoizing the results i.e if we are computing `editDistance(t, S[1, 2, 3, 4])` we could re-use the computation from `S[1, 2, 3]`)
4. The other option I could think of is to construct a [Trie or DAWG (Directed Acyclic Word Graph)](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/?id=114)

But, I'm not an expert on this, so I might be missing a better solution. How would we do this efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a good question. Could you please give reference to where you find this problem?

Comment: What are the constraints on the running time of the algorithm?

Comment: Concatenation is not defined for a set.  Do you mean "among all permutations" or is S a sequence ?

Comment: If the strings in s, and t have roughly the same length, most minimal matchings should be with a single string, because m deletions (to reach the same length) compete with m substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try all possible permutation and combination of the set $S$. There are exactly $\sum_{r = 1} ^{8} \mathsf{8Pr}$ such possibilities for $n = 8$. This sums to exactly [109600](https://oeis.org/A007526).

For each subset $s^*$ of $S$, find the edit distance to target string $t$ using the [standard DP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). This will take time $l_S \times l$ where $l_S$ is the total length of all the strings in $S$ and $l$ is the length of string $t$. Since $l_S$ could be $400$ and $l$ could be $50$, the total running time is ~ $ 2 \times 10^9$.

You can further optimize the algorithm. In the [standard DP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), the algorithm stores the minimum edit distance of all the pairs of suffixes of two given strings $a$ and $b$.  In the current problem, the string $t$ is fixed; however $concat(s^*)$ varies depending on subset $s^*$. However, note that some suffixes of $concat(s^*)$ overlaps for different $s^*$. You can show that there at most $S_l \cdot (nC0 + nC1 + nC2 + \dotsc + nCn)$ possible different suffixes of the concatenated string $concat(s^*)$ over all possible subsets $s^{*}$ for $n = 8$. This sums to at most $S_l \cdot 2^{8} \leq 102400$. Thus, the algorithm only needs to find edit distance of $102400 \times 50$ possible pairs of suffixes. Thus, the algorithm can be implemented in ~ $5 \times 10^{6}$ computation steps, which is doable in $1$ sec on regular personal computers.